# gcc: suppress [enabled by default] warning from c++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, suppress-warnings

We build our project using gcc with -Wall -Werror options.
Warnings from external headers are suppressed by pragmas, like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#include <somelib/component/settings.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

After upgrading externals to new version we got new type of warnings to suppress:

```
error: inline function ‘...’ given attribute noinline [-Werror]
```

Or warning without -Werror:

```
warning: inline function ‘...’ given attribute noinline [enabled by default]
```

In seems there is no way to ignore it via #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored.

What can be done in this case under following conditions?

1. External headers cannot be modified. Patching local copy at build time is acceptable as a last resort.
2. Problematic header is widely used.
3. `-Werror` is on for our code

Comment: Patch the code and submit a change request with the tested patch to the upstream author.

Comment: Patching is a viable solution for open source dependencies only. It's impossible for proprietary external library.

Finally we have choosen to patch at build time with cmake `execute_process(COMMAND "patch" "-N" ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have chosen to patch at build time. It's a bit hacky but it allows to leave our project intact.

Patching was added to cmake build:

`execute_process(COMMAND "patch" "-N" "header_to_patch.h" "header_to_patch.h.patch")`

Patch file was prepared with:

`diff -u "original/header_to_patch.h" "fixed/header_to_patch.h" > header_to_patch.h.patch`